# C# draw to bitmap from 2nd thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, picturebox

I'm trying to draw to a `public static Bitmap`, which is the Image of my `PictureBox`-`Control`. The drawing works fine in same thread, but when I start a 2nd thread nothing happens, nothing is drawn. Does anyone know a solution?

Code to draw:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screen);  
g.Clear(Color.Black);Brushes.White);  
g.Dispose();
```

//Edit:
Please excuse me. The Bitmap is stored in anaother class called Form1. The threads class is DrawHelper. To get acces to the Bitmap I gave DrawHelper the reference of Form1 with this (calling from Form1).
I hope this helps. I can post all the code, but there would be so much unnecessary code.

Comment: We're going to need more code than that.  My suspicion, though, would be that the bitmap somehow isn't making the jump between threads.  What are you doing to transfer the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bitmap is bound to the form window message loop. if you are trying to access anything like that you have to use Invoke or BeginInvoke.

Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

**EDIT.** After reading the comment I can tell you that you have a bug and the bitmap just dont get the information you think it gets. There is nothing to do with using threads per se...

If you really need to solve it you should create simple prototype with 2 threads one button and a bitmap and just try to draw anything from thread #2 and see what doesnt work. if even this wont work - post the code here. (Please dont copy/paste the whole app - keep it to a point)

**Also** you should put try/catch inside using. The bitmap may behave the way it does simply because there is invisible exception inside the using.

Comment: I'm using Invoke. Without Invoke I get an exception, as expected.

Comment: I'm invoking. There is now exception. The Bitmap just don't change.

Comment: Sorry for tripple-post *blame*. There is no exception.